# How do I count the number of elements in a table using a script on Azure?

Tags: javascript, sql, azure, count

I need to make an online leaderboard for a videogame.
I'm using a Mobile Service on Azure. I have a table which should contain only the first 100 scores (highest, of course) so before this number of records is reached, every score should be admitted.
To do this, I need to count the number of the rows of my Leaderboard table in my insert script on Azure.

The default script is:

```
function insert(item, user, request) {
   request.execute();
}
```

And my query would be something like:

```
SELECT COUNT (*)  
FROM Leaderboard
```

I tried to use **mssql.query** but it's like that part of code is ignored.

```
var sql = "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM Leaderboard";

    mssql.query(sql, {
        success: function(results){
            //do things
        },
        error: function(err) {
            console.log("error: " + err);
        }
    });
```

I also tried:

```
var LeaderboardOnlineTable = tables.getTable('LeaderboardOnline');

LeaderboardOnlineTable.take(0).includeTotalCount().read().then(function (results) {
        var count = results.totalCount;
    });
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd like to see how do you call the insert function and also I'd want to know what actually is your problem. Isn't this working?

Comment: The insert function is automatically called when a record in inserted in the table, I don't think it's relevant for my question. My problem is that the query is not executed, I tried to add some debugging code in "success" and "error" but both don't work (putting the code outside the query works) and I can't figure out why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
function insert(item, user, request) {
    var LeaderboardOnlineTable = tables.getTable('LeaderboardOnline');
    LeaderboardOnlineTable.includeTotalCount().read({success: insertRecord});

    function insertRecord(results) {
        var count = results.totalCount;
        if (count < 100) {
            request.execute();
        } else {
            // do whatever you need if the table is "full"
        }
    }
}
```